# Setear un valor de una combobox o select con Jquery mediante el texto y no el valor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Habitualmente para setear un valor de una combobox con Jquery, se hace a traves del val, por ejemplo, en el Html:

```
<select id="combobox" >
<option value='1'>Uno</option>
<option value='2'>Dos</option>
<option value='3'>Tres</option>
</select>
```

Y para dejar seleccionado el valor dos con Jquery, se hace así:

```
$("#combobox").val(2);
```

Pero lo que deseo es setearlo mediante la palabra, algo como esto:

```
 $("#combobox").text("Dos");
```

Lo cual lo intenté, pero no resulta, me gustaría saber si posible hacer esto, y como se podría hacer.

Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: ¿En qué contexto o evento lo estás intentando? Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el contexto real del código para verificarlo.

Comment: @A. Cedano, gracias por responder, pero no se en que parte no me explique bien, la idea es dejar seleccionado el valor mediante el texto y no con el valor. Es decir en el option dejar selected mediante el valor Dos del texto y no con el 2

Comment: Pues ahora entiendo menos. Para dejar un valor seleccionado tienes que ponerle `selected`, algo así:  `<option value='2' selected>Dos</option>` Sea como sea, muestra el escenario real donde lo estás intentando y no funciona, quizá así entendamos el problema. Fíjate que parece sencillo, pero no se entiende. Esta explicación que da es confusa: *la idea es dejar seleccionado el valor mediante el texto y no con el valor. Es decir en el option dejar selected mediante el valor Dos del texto y no con el 2*

Comment: Lo que se interpreta ahí es que cuando el `text()` sea igual a `Dos` ese option se establezca en  `selected` ... ¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: @A.Cedano, si, eso es, mediante el texto Dos

Comment: @A.Cedano, como lo digo. Tienes definido tu comobox, pero para setearlo o dejarlo con el <option value='2' selected>Dos</option>, facilmente le aplico con Jquery el valor 2, es decir :
$("#combobox").val(2);
Pero yo desde la Base de Datos no tengo el valor 2, sino la palabra Dos, y a traves de eso, dejar establecido con el selected a la opción dos

Comment: Pon el código que estás usando, así podremos decirte lo que está mal. No veo que verifiques nada en tu código, no veo en qué evento debe ocurrir la verificación o si debe hacerse cuando se carga el `select`, no se sabe si usas Ajax, etc. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano, estimado, con todo el respeto que se merecer, no se porque necesita mas información o le cuesta entender, pero ya encontré la solución y la publique

Answer (score 0):

Basta son solo colocar esto:

```
$("#combobox option").filter(function () {                                       
    return $(this).text() == "Dos";
 }).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Falta un espacio: `$("#combobox option").filter(function () {`, En cuanto a mis comentarios anteriores, en este sitio es costumbre pedir que se muestre el código real con el que se está trabajando. Eso facilita la comprensión del problema y agiliza cualquier respuesta. En la pregunta no se entendía lo que querías.

Comment: gracias @A. Cedano, pero ya había mostrado codigo suficiente y un titulo descriptivo de lo que pedía. Por ejemplo lo saque de aquí:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description/32589732

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto otras 2 maneras diferentes de hacerlo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name=selectNow]').on('click',function(event) {
        selectByText( $.trim( $('input[name=selText]').val() ) );
    }).click();
});

function selectByText( txt ) {
    
    //Opcion #1
    $("#combobox option:contains(" + txt + ")").attr('selected', true);
   
    //Opcion #2
    //$('#combobox').find("option:contains(" + txt + ")").attr('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="combobox" >
<option value='1'>Uno</option>
<option value='2'>Dos</option>
<option value='3'>Tres</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Select By Text: <br>
<input type="text" name="selText" value="">
<input type="button" name="selectNow" value="Select Now">
```

**Nota:** Ambos métodos solo funcionan con la versión **1.8.3 (o inferior) de jQuery**.